# attr_accessor breaks 2 of my methods in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, attr-accessor

I have a User model.  One of its attributes is a string called `:access` which can be either nil, "admin", or "active".

Now inside the User model I have the following methods:

```
def admin?
  self.access == "admin"
end

def active?
  self.access == "active"
end
```

They work fine.  But if I add `attr_accessor :access` to the model something breaks. My `admin?` and `active?` methods no longer work.  When I go into rails console and get a User out of the database I can see that `user = User.find(7)` shows `access` is set to "admin".  But if I type `user.access` it returns `nil`.  `user.admin?` returns `false`.

Comment: is access already a column in the database?

Comment: Can you be more specific re: what breaks?  Do you get a specific error, etc.  Also, do you already have access as attr_accessible in the User model?

Comment: Well the original problem was that rspec was giving me an error that access= is missing.  So I thought I needed to add an accessor for :acesss.  But when I did that, my admin? and active? methods started returning nil

Answer (score 2):

`attr_accessor` is overwriting the default methods of reading and writing an attribute from db. Why do you need `attr_accessor` if it is already a column in db and `Rails` provides you with the read and write methods. Are you confusing it with `attr_accessible`?

Comment: The reason is that rspec gives me an error telling me that access= is undefined.  So I thought I needed an accessor for it.

Comment: that seems like Rspec issue, you can remove `attr_accessor` and try `access =` in console to see if it works outside RSpec.